# I want to display values on textview through JSONParser using given url

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to display about_builder of given `JSON` url, but I am not able to declare properly `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` on `MainActivity`, so please anyone help me to display the data on `TextView`. 
Error shown:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.and_ws_builder/com.example.and_ws_builder.MainActivity}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

MainActivity.java class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {   
        private static String url ="http://myfourwalls.in/services_microsite/project_builder.php";
        private static final String TAG_Name = "about_builder";
        JSONArray builder = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();        
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFormUrl(url);        
            try {

                builder = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Name);
                 JSONObject c = builder.getJSONObject(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_Name);                
                    final TextView nam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                    nam.setText(name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {
     static InputStream is = null;
     static JSONObject jobj = null;
     static String json = "";
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFormUrl(String url) {  
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
                sb.append(line +"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Buffer Error","Error converting result" + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            jobj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parse","error Parsing data" + e.toString());
        }
        return jobj;
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/txtname"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are using Network related code in main thread. Use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Network related code in main thread. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling network calls inside the main thread means foreground which is not supported in android.So use assynctask class which will handle network calls in background.

1)inside on create method call like:

```
new GetJson().execute();
```

2) declare the following outside oncreate

```
     private class GetJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        JSONObject c=null;
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();        
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFormUrl(url);        
            try {

                builder = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Name);
                 c = builder.getJSONObject(0);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return c;
      }

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject result) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                    String name = result.getString(TAG_Name);                
                    final TextView nam = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                    nam.setText(name);
                }





}
```